# Drawing view on iOS

Tags: drawing, ios

How can I implement a view for users to draw in (specifically sign their name)?  I would greatly prefer a library or sample code to implementing it myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing a curved line is just a series of filled circles or small straight lines. A kind of differentiation.

1. Track user's previous & current touch points. (`UITouch`)
2. Just draw a line which connect the points. (Or draw any shape what you want, just fill the gap)

**Basics**

There are series of methods for tracking touches.

```
– touchesMoved:withEvent:
– touchesEnded:withEvent:
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

These methods are on `UIView`.(methods themselves are defined in `UIResponder` which is superclass of it) 
Override them. In most cases tracking touch point is not a problem.

And send `setNeedsDisplay` message to UIView itself to make it invalidate it's graphics state so it will redraw itself soon.

Override `drawRect` method of the `UIView` to draw something (like black disk) you need with **Quartz** (`CGContext`). You may store tracked touch points to draw each lines. Basically, you have to redraw all of touch trails.

**Optimization**

- You can cache drawn image as a bitmap (`CGImage` which can be retrieved `UIImage`). So you need to draw just newly added touch points.
- You can draw on bitmap directly by setting drawing context to the bitmap. And just display it via UIImage.
- You can use OpenGL ES texture drawing. This is fastest, but hardest. And requires totally different approach for performance gain.

More detailed informations and samples are on reference of methods/classes I mentioned. I attach a link:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html#section=Topics&topic=Graphics%20%26amp%3B%20Animation